# How do I retrieve data from two tables in Django using postgresql

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

In my views.py this is my code:

```
def search(request):
qset = Q()
query = request.GET.get('q', '')
queryC = request.GET.get('clients', '')
queryD = request.GET.get('documents', '')
queryT = request.GET.get('topics', '')
if query:
    newquery = stopwords.strip_stopwords(query)
    terms = newquery.split()
    if queryT != 'empty':
        for term in terms:
            qset |= (
                Q(Topic_id__Name__icontains=queryT) &
                Q(Question_id__Statement__icontains=term)
            )
        results = Response.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
    else:
        for term in terms:
            qset &= (
                Q(Question_id__Statement__icontains=term)
            )
        results = Response.objects.filter(qset).distinct()
else:
    results = []
return render_to_response("app/search.html", {
    "results": results,
    "query": query
})
```

models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    Topic_id = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Statement = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Question')
    Keyword = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Keyword')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Statement


class Response(models.Model):
    Question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Topic_id = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Response = models.TextField(default='Response')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Response
```

It returns the responses that is closely related to the query from user input. But I also want it to return the question that is linked to the response.

My response table has a foreign key to the question table linked by Questions_id. I've read I might have to use select_related() but not sure how to.

Comment: You should show your models. Almost certainly you don't need to do anything specific, just follow the foreign key in the template.

Comment: (Incidentally, using `set()` there seems odd; why are you doing that?)

Comment: We can ignore the set(), was trying to get rid of duplicate responses but it was a database issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a queryset of Responses. As you iterate through in your template, you can follow the foreign key to the related question:

```
{% for response in results %}
  {{ response.Response }}
  {{ response.Question_id.Statement }}
{% endfor %}
```

The use of select_related is an optimisation here, in that it will get the related questions as a JOIN rather than making separate queries. It is *not* (and *never*) required. But it is a good idea here.

```
results = Response.objects.filter(qset).select_related('Question_id').distinct()
```

A couple of style points. It is Pythonic to use lower case for attribute names: `statement`, `keyword` etc. More importantly, you should not use `_id` for your ForeignKey fields; despite the name, the fields themselves are not actually ids, as they give access to the entire related object (as I show above). So you should call them `question`, `topic`, etc.

Comment: I think I tried that and got this error:

ProgrammingError at /search/
column app_question.Topic_id_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "app_question"."id", "app_question"."Topic_id_id", "a...

Comment: That has nothing to do with this question, that is a problem with your model definitions. As I say, you shouldn't be using `Topic_id` as a field name, it should be just `topic`. But how did you get in this state anyway? Have you made and run the migrations?

Comment: my mistake, inside postgresql the foreign key is Question_id_id. I've never done any development work before so I am not use to writing pythonic code

Comment: {% for resp in results %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ resp|escape|linebreaks }}</td>
            <td>{{ resp.Question_id_id.Statement }}</td>
        </tr>
{ % endfor %}

I have this in my search.html but the questions are not being populated

Comment: But you're confusing the Django field with the underlying database column. You need to use the Django field, as I said above: `{{ resp.Question_id.Statement }}`.

Comment: Ah my problem was in the models.py. Had to remove some fields. Thank you for your help!